# How can we implement separate day, month year selector in html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, date, drop-down-menu

[image]

As per screen, I want to implement birth_date field selector with different box for date, month, year along with the dropdown list.

I have written the haml code as below

```
.input-holder.
  %label{for: 'birth_date'} Birthday
  %br
  .input-group
    %select{id: "", name: ""}
      %option{value: ""} 01
      %option{value: ""} 02
      %option{value: ""} 03
    %select{id: "", name: ""}
      %option{value: ""} 01
      %option{value: ""} 02
      %option{value: ""} 03
    %select{id: "", name: ""}
      %option{value: ""} 1995
      %option{value: ""} 1996
      %option{value: ""} 1997
      %option{value: ""} 1998
```

but writing all the option is not good idea.

I want 1 to 31 range for the date, 1 to 12 for month and years can be list till current year

And while submitting the form, it pass combile as date for :birth_date field.
Here :birth_date field is date field

Answer (score 1):

Rails already have a helper for that: `date_select`

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you right, maybe you need something like this?

```
.input
  %label{for: 'birth_date'} Birthday
  %br
.input-group
  %select{id: "", name: ""}
    - (1..31).each do |j|
      %option{value: ""} #{j}
```

p.s. I don't strong in haml, and I haven't know how to check count of days depending on month